# How can I fix "error C2146: syntax error : missing ';'"?

Tags: c++

I hate to ask for help on such a common error but I've been staring and prodding at my code for two hours trying to find what the compiler says is a missing semi-colon and unspecified type:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'history'.....: 
> error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int 1>c:\users\alex\dropbox\lab4\lab4\lab4\customer.h(49):
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
using std::string;
#include "customerdata.h"
#include "rentalhistory.h"
#include "item.h"
#include "customer.h"
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Purpose: class Customer contains methods to grab information about a customer, 
such as their id number, address, phone number (stored in class CustomerData). 
It also contains methods that will allow access to information about a 
customer’s rental history (stored in class RentalHistory).

CONSTRUCTION:
(1) empty construction. (2) name and id (3) with information provided by
CustomerData object.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
class Customer
{
public:
    Customer();
    Customer( const Customer & );
    Customer( string, string, int );
    Customer( const CustomerData & );
    ~Customer();

    // get customer's first name.
    string getFirstName() const;

    // get customer's last name.
    string getLastName() const;

    // get customer's id number
    int getIdNum() const;

    // add a movie to customer's rental history
    void addMovie( Item *&, string code );

    // checks to see if it is a valid customer
    bool isValidCustomer();

    // prints the customer's rental history
    void printHistory() const;

    Customer & operator=( Customer &rhs );


private:
    CustomerData data;  // object that contains customer's information
    RentalHistory history; // object that contains customer's rental history
};
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't define `RentalHistory`. Can we see your headers?

Comment: It's possible that the error is in customerdata.h, rentalhistory.h, item.h, or customer.h.  Simplify your code even more so that we can actually compile it and try it ourselves.  Read http://sscce.org

Comment: David Grayson, thanks for the link. Next time I post I'll prepare a SSCCE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message indicates that the compiler doesn't recognize `RentalHistory` as a type. If the type is correctly defined in the included `rentalhistory.h`, the most common reason for such a problem would be circular dependencies.

Does `rentalhistory.h` try to include `customer.h`? In this case you have circular includes that you need to resolve. In `rentalhistory.h` you would most likely have to add a forward declaration like `class Customer;` instead of including `customer.h`.

Also: Why does `customer.h` try to include itself?

Comment: Thanks, sth. You were right about the circular dependencies. I've included the forward declaration. Do I only include the header of the class I forward declarated in the .cpp file?

Comment: Yes, including the header in the .cpp file should do the right thing.